# Uitextview trimmed in ios 13

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview, ios13

Since iOS 13.1.3 uitextview is trimmed ... this is not in iOS 12.2.

Any help is welcome!

See reports how uitextview presentation differs on iOS 12.2 and IOS 13.1.3
Has it something todo with xcode versie 10.2 and 11?

View in ios 12.2 with xcode 10.2
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/2snbG.jpg)

View in ios 13 with xcode 11
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zqudq.jpg)

The text in the ios 13 report is trimmed... same code different xcode and ios versions

Comment: I have another issue - for some reason, Text View does not automatically change its size on iPad running 13.2, but it does in on previous versions of iOS and Simulator with 13.2. The code is the same. It looks like a UIKit bug for me.

I'll answer if find something about this, but no much so far

Comment: Hi, did you already has a solution?